# 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-7

I'm getting the following exception while making a call using XMLHttp object asynchronously in Mozilla Firefox.

```
407 Proxy Authentication Required
The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request.
Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.
```

#### Description of cause:

Actually I'm trying to make an asynchronous request to using get in javascript. It is working fine using IE 6 but for IE 7 and Firefox 3.5, it will it won't get any data using asynchronous request so how to overcome this problem?

When I debug in Firefox 3.5 using firebug it shows

```
407 Proxy Authentication Required The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfil the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.
```

exception at console so how to tackle this issue

Note: our network has proxy server

Comment: do you have proxy server? authenticate with your proxy server

Comment: but how to authenticate using javascript

Comment: Two things, is your call going to the server your app is on? If not, you cannot do AJAX xml calls to remote servers (you need to opt for a **jsonp** call instead). Other than that, authentication needs server interaction and therefore afaik cannot be handled client-side.

Comment: actually i am trying to make async request to using get in javascript it is working fine for ie6 but for ie 7 and firefox 3.5 it will it wont get any data using async request so how to overcome this problem
when i debug in firfox 3.5 using firebug it shows 

407 Proxy Authentication Required The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfil the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.

exception at console so how to tackle this issue

Note : our network has proxy server

Answer (score 6):

I recognize I am a little late to the party here, and this question, however, I was having the exact same problem.  @FK82 indicated the right solution and I wanted to document it, as I've tried it and it works.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://somefancyurl.com/api/do_it",
    data: { id:"user" },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

If I **do not specify jsonp** I get the *407 Proxy Authentication Required* error.

- Although the original question didn't specify JQuery, I was able to test successfully with FireFox 3.6.x, and IE7 using this approach & JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

Proxy Authentication is simply an existence of a http header field called `"Proxy-Authorization"`

Browsers are supposed to send those stuff automatically.

But since you could add some custom header to ajax requests, you could try setting it manually.

```
request.setRequestHeader("Proxy-Authorization", value);
```

- **request** is the XMLHttp object
- **value** is the base64 encoded version of `username:password`

Note that I am not sure thats the case or not, correct me if I am wrong.

Or some page I found on google says to add `X-Requested-With`, may be worth to try that too.

```
request.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
```

Comment: thanks for your response but i make other work around for this issue and handled that one at server side itself rather than client side
But i will try your suggestion also

Comment: this answer assumes the proxy is using basic authentication, which won't be true in many cases.