# detect a 407 error and persist for all subsequent requests

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, jsonp

I have a simple javascript that uses $.ajax() from JQuery which works great for GET/POST.  However, for some users that are behind a proxy, they receive the 407 error as outlined in the post below.

[407 Proxy Authentication Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808590/407-proxy-authentication-required)

Now, as you will see, I've updated that post stating that the usage of **JSONP** will suffice as a workaround.  Where I'm at now, is I don't want to use JSONP all the time, only when it is required.

```
 function original() {
     $.ajax({
         url: "http://somecool.url/foo",
         data: { id:"bar"},
         statusCode: {
             407: foo()
         },
         success: function(data) {
             $.each(data, function(k,v) {
                 $('#foo').append("<li>" + k + ":" + v + "</li>");
             });
         }
     });
 }    


 function foo() {
     $.ajax({
         url: "http://somecool.url/foo",
         data: { id:"bar" },
         dataType: "jsonp",
         success: function(data) {
             $.each(data, function(k,v) {
                 $('#foo').append("<li>" + k + ":" + v + "</li>");
             });
         }
     });
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
     original();
 });
```

Is it possible to persist the status of the first failure, which returns the 407 error when there is a proxy issue so that all subsequent requests do not go to the `original()` function and go to the `foo()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original answer (below) was dealing with function name override to accommodate the code in your question. However, there's a better solution, since after all you only want to switch all requests to JSONP if and only if you receive a `407` response code.

[$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) was designed to do exactly that:

```
function original() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://somecool.url/foo",
        data: { id:"bar"},
        statusCode: {
             407: function() {
                 $.ajaxSetup({ dataType: "jsonp" });
                 // Now all AJAX requests use JSONP, retry.
                 original();
             }
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(k,v) {
                $('#foo').append("<li>" + k + ":" + v + "</li>");
            });
        }
    });
}
```

With this strategy, once `407` is received, all the future AJAX requests will use JSONP.

---

---

*For the sake of history, here is my original answer.*

You can permanently change the function stored in `original` when you receive a `407` response code for the first time:

```
function original() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://somecool.url/foo",
        data: { id:"bar"},
        statusCode: {
             407: function() {
                 window.original = foo;
                 foo();
             }
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(k,v) {
                $('#foo').append("<li>" + k + ":" + v + "</li>");
            });
        }
    });
}
```

From then on, the name `original` will refer to `foo()`. You can even change the function and call its replacement at the same time:

```
407: function() {
    (window.original = foo)();
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify .. ajaxSetup() and the settings made exist only for the life of that page ... if the user navigates away and comes back, it'll have to re-setup again?  I guess the only way I'll get around this is via sessions or cookies .. great answer though, thanks.